# Find and replace string using regex in VSCode

Tags: php, regex, visual-studio-code

I have some PHP code in my project with below syntax

```
methoxyz($randomVar1, true);
methoxyz($randomVar['xyz'], true);
```

I want to replace above syntax like below,

```
methoxyz($randomVar1);
methoxyz($randomVar['xyz']);
```

Replace **", true"** where **"methoxyz"** used.
How can I do this in VSCode? I am new to regex.

Comment: Can you confirm if `methoxyz` can take only 2 parameters?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/uKjAtb/1

Comment: @nice_dev yes it takes only 2 parameters.

Comment: @nice_dev the question is not how many parameters but what is the complexity of the first argument, in your regex101 you have a string with `()` and that makes the regex more complex, maybe the second parameter has a default value, can the call be present on a line more than once, you have to check all hits VSC finds before you perform the replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find: `methoxyz\(([^)]+), true\);`

replace: `methoxyz($1);`

You have to do the occasions where the first argument is a complex expression with `()` by hand

Alternative:

find: `methoxyz\((.+?), true\);`

There could be occasions where this fails if there is a call to `methoxyz` without a `true` followed by a call to `methoxyz` with `true`.

Comment: methoxyz\((.+?), true\); helped me to find all the occurrence, thanks.